# Blender: How can i "automatically" connect randomized image textures to a principled shader? Python

Tags: python, blender

Im Using Blender 3.0, How do i "auto" connect randomized image texture to a Shader socket?

I have a few objects in a scene that have a set of 4 different image textures being "randomized" with a white noise node and some math and mixrgb nodes to get a random image texture every frame.
[Blender shader node ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrEmj.png)

lets say i save out 10 separate .blend file for every frame, meaning each blend file has different random object textures.

how would i go about "automatically" connecting the "randomized" texture to the principledBsdf base color socket, for every object in the scene?

barely know what im doing in python, may help somehow :P

```
for x in bpy.objects/collection 
  get scene objects with Randomized textures
  get the active image texture and connect it to principled bsdf, 
  Basecolor socket
  delete image textures not used
```

[Blender shader node ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrEmj.png)

Comment: Did you ask in [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)? It might help :)

Comment: Thank you, just submitted there as well :)